# .eps graph overlapped with caption

Tags: captions, graphs

I need your help desperately. I used latex to compile everything and used dvipdf to convert it to pdf. The graph (test) came out is overlapped with the caption. Can anyone point out what is the problem here? A million thanks!!!! :D You can go to ***LOOK HERE*** to check out the problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}      % Use this line for a4
                                                          % paper
\oddsidemargin -4mm %
\topmargin -15mm %
\textheight 250mm %
\textwidth 168mm %
\marginparsep 20mm

\pagenumbering{arabic} \pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}


% The following packages can be found on http:\\www.ctan.org
\usepackage{graphicx} % for pdf, bitmapped graphics files
\usepackage{epsfig} % for postscript graphics files
%\usepackage{mathptmx} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
%\usepackage{times} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{amsmath} % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amssymb}  % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{psfrag}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
%\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{property}{Property}[section]
%\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\newcommand{\bea}{\begin{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\eea}{\end{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\be}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\ee}{\end{equation}}
\newcommand{\ba}{\begin{array}}
\newcommand{\ea}{\end{array}}
\newcommand{\bdm}{\begin{displaymath}}
\newcommand{\edm}{\end{displaymath}}
\newcommand{\p}{\partial}
\newcommand{\paf}[1]{\frac{\partial}{\partial{#1}}}
\newcommand{\re}[1]{(\ref{#1})}
\newcommand{\sgn}{\textrm{sgn}}
\newcommand{\cdeg}{\,^{\circ}\mathrm{C}}
\newcommand{\ud}{\mathrm{d}}

\title{\bf{Modeling and Robust Tracking Control of a Limited Angle Torque Motor with Cylindrical Halbach}}

\author{Tan Xin Wen \vspace{0.1in}\\ U1120572E \vspace{0.1in}\\ Industrial Orientation \vspace{0.1in}\\
School of Electrical and Electronics Engineering \vspace{0.1in}\\ Nanyang Technological University}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\newpage\section{Extended}

*******LOOK HERE*******
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{test.eps}
\caption{Tracking error $\tilde\theta$ and state estimation errors $\theta$ - $\hat\theta$, $\dot\theta$ - $\hat{\dot\theta}$ - $\dot\theta$ and $\hat{\ddot\theta}$ - $\ddot\theta$}
\label{fig:Tracking error}
\end{figure}

Helo helo. testing...


\newpage\section{Model}

\newpage\section{Tracking}


%\\includegraphics[]{test}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Even though you posted a long snippet of code, it is almost impossible to detect the problem as we can not see your picture `test.eps`. It would be better to provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/13304).

Comment: provide the image for a download

Comment: (1) Reduce the MWE to only what is needed. (2) try using `\fbox{\includegraphics...}}` to see if the `EPS` bounding box is wrong. If it is you may need to change it manually. (3) If (2) fails, please upload the `EPS` somewhere. Otherwise it is impossible to help.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem (which is presumably an incorrect bounding box in the eps file) load `graphicx` not `epsfig`, use teh ams alignments such as `align` rather than `eqnarray` (and don't make abbreviations such as `\newcommand{\bea}{\begin{eqnarray}}` which don't work with amsmath and obscure the latex structure anyway and don't use `[h]` (which usually generates a warning from LaTeX that it is changing it to `[ht]`